# Problem with Jenkins / bloom-release

Tags: ros, jenkins, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am struggling with a persistent error with one of my packages: in the past we have done several releases (bloom-release) without problems, but since a few weeks ago Jenkins is persistently complaining about:

```
Invoking 'git clone --branch debian/ros-kinetic-mrpt-ekf-slam-3d_0.1.1-0_jessie --depth 1 --no-single-branch https://github.com/mrpt-ros-pkg-release/mrpt_slam-release.git /tmp/sourcedeb/source'
Cloning into '/tmp/sourcedeb/source'...
fatal: Remote branch debian/ros-kinetic-mrpt-ekf-slam-3d_0.1.1-0_jessie not found in upstream origin
```

Indeed, that branch does not exist: I can only see these tags:

```
debian/ros-kinetic-mrpt-ekf-slam-3d_0.1.1-0_xenial
debian/ros-kinetic-mrpt-ekf-slam-3d_0.1.1-0_willy
```

Here is the complete log:
http://build.ros.org/job/Ksrc_dJ__mrpt_ekf_slam_3d__debian_jessie__source/26/console

My actual questions are:

1. Is there something that I might have done wrong while releasing the package with `bloom-release`?
2. If not, how can I fix it, apart of doing a "fake" new release as a workaround?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243556/problem-with-jenkins-/-bloom-release/) by [Jose Luis Blanco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2046/jose-luis-blanco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 288 on 2016-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you ran `bloom` it probably mentioned a problem when creating the release for Debian Jessie. Most likely due to some missing dependencies. You can either look in the `~/.bloom/logs` (or similar) folder for the console output or just try to run it again.

If a dependency is not defined for Jessie you can contribute the missing rule to the rosdistro repo and after it had been merged a new release should pass for Jessie.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-09-27**:
Same error on my project [here](http://build.ros.org/job/Ksrc_dJ__rtabmap__debian_jessie__source/). When I do bloom-release, no errors, "jessie" is just not processed, only debian "willy", "xenial"  and rpm "23", "24". bloom version = `0.5.20`

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-09-28**:
nevermind, I had an old version of bloom-release from http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python-bloom (`0.5.20`), upgrading to version in http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu (`0.5.22`) solved the problem.